# export/import Eclipse build path

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I like Eclipse's build path features, but would like to keep it in sync with my ant `build.xml`. Is there a way to either automatically import the Eclipse build path from a text file, or export the Eclipse build path to a text file, so I can use that file from ant? (if I can get to a text file, I know I can figure out how to get ant to use that file as its javac build path)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a way to either automatically import the Eclipse build path from a text file, or **export the Eclipse build path to a text file**, so I can use that file from ant?

The Eclipse build path already is a text file (.classpath):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ojdbc14_g.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe **[ant4eclipse](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102232151/http://ant4eclipse.sourceforge.net:80/ant-for-eclipse-home.html)** is the tool (plugin) you need.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://ant4eclipse.sourceforge.net/images/ant-for-eclipse-logo-small.gif))</sub>

> The aim of the `ant4eclipse` project is to avoid (or at least: to reduce) the redundancy of Eclipse and Ant configurations.
>   More precisely: it consists of **Ant tasks that are able to read and work with some of Eclipse's configuration files**. With these tasks you're able to:
>
> - Setup classpathes as defined in Eclipse' .classpath-file
> - checkout complete workspaces as it's possible with the Team Project Set feature of eclipse
> - run your Java applications as you have defined them in an Eclipse Launch Configuration
>
> With all these tasks you're able to create a complete automatic build system that starts with checking out all required projects from CVS, builds all projects in the correct order with classpath settings as specified in Eclipse, and to launch your applications as they are specified in Eclipse.
>   And the best of it: if you or someone else changes a configuration in Eclipse, those changes are immediately visible to your buildfiles - without changing one line of code!

Comment: We are using it with our Hudson builds.  It took quite a bit of elbow grease to come from the configuration to functional code, as we have multi-project applications.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Eclipse 3.4 (I think) you can "export" a project into ant files.  Choose "Export..." by right clicking on a project.  Under "General" is "Ant Buildfiles".  It generates an ant file that you could use to recompile the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your jars in a well known location and in the ant build just add all those jars.

Then configure eclipse specifically in terms of the jars it requires. I want eclipse to be specific about the jars it requires, because I'm concerned about compile time, but with ant it's less of a concern - it's normally a fire and forget build.

Comment: This approach scales badly (just imagine how to handle multiple versions of the same jar, updates, etc) and was why Maven was created.